# PHP Socket timeout won't go below 0.5 seconds

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to scan an ip range and get info from specific devices.
Problem is, although i have `SO_RCVTIMEO` to `array('sec'=>0,'usec'=>1000)`
each request that should timeout gets around `0.5 seconds`. The others on the other hand only take `0.005 seconds`. You can imagine that if i want to scan a big IP range then i'm doomed.

What am i doing wrong or how can i improve it ?

Below is the code

```
foreach($ipArray as $ip){
    $result = array();
    $buf = '';
    $from = '';
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_set_option($sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,$timeout);
    socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1);
    //socket_bind($sock, $from, 2048);
    socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 0);
    socket_sendto($sock, $data1, strlen($data1), 0, $ip, 10001);
    $time = microtime(true);
    if(!socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512000, 0, $from, $port)){
        echo (microtime(true) - $time) . ' elapsed<br><br><br>';
        continue;
    }
    echo (microtime(true) - $time) . ' elapsed<br><br><br>';
    $result= parse_result(bin2hex($buf));
    socket_close($sock);
}
```

Note that i'm creating a separate socket for each IP because for some reason otherwise results would get confused in between the ips and i would sometimes get the same result twice.

Running this on a Windows Bitnami machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Windows has a minimum amount of timeout you can set which is way higher than that on linux.

Basically the `array('sec'=>0,'usec'=>1000)` usec part of it only works in Linux machines.